# toolset for wordpress theme development recommendation

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, workflow, wordpress-theming

What are the best toolset you can recommend in developing wordpress theme? Are the tools you use to make the workflow fast? Actually I'm looking for a stacked of codes or snippet that developers gathered and just reuse it in their development. (e.g. the wordpress loop, customized loop, ) the loop can then just be copy and pasted. If this doesn't exist, can you recommend some techniques or tools you use to make the development fast? cos i'm think i'm doing it all wrong starting from always from scratch. I also tried using "Starkers Naked theme". I just hope they provide snippets to achieve some common functionality of a theme (e.g. loop to spit custom fields, control of pages, etc.  )

I know this can be considered in DocType because it talks about wordpress, but it also deals in programming and making the workflow fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three (3) similar questions each with lots of answers from [StackOverflow's sister site **WordPress Answers**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/):

- [**Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)
- [**Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324/software-for-wordpress-theme-and-plugin-development)
- [**What process do you use for WordPress development?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/617/what-process-do-you-use-for-wordpress-development)

I'll bet you'll find your questions more than answered by those three posts.

Hope this helps.

-Mike

Comment: Awesome find mike. Thanks for collecting it for me. :) Your Awesome!